# Pre-load CSV file into an array in Objective-C for iOS app [during Startup]

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, core-data, preload

I have an array of size 32x1 as follows:

> 0.0873
>   0.0916
>   0.0711
>   0.0618
>   0.0736
>   0.0818
>   0.0785
>   0.1301
>   0.0914
>   0.0596
>   0.0807
>   0.0623
>   0.0979
>   0.0605
>   0.0708
>   0.0732
>   0.0864
>   0.0689
>   0.1032
>   0.1063
>   0.0506
>   0.0585
>   0.1077
>   0.0422
>   0.0714
>   0.0625
>   0.0693
>   0.0762
>   0.0646
>   0.0855
>   0.0990
>   0.0691

I have saved them in a csv file. I have similar csv files with 17408 elements. Currently, I am reading the csv files using NSScanner, which is done while I execute the program.

I want to know if it is possible to store the array during the app startup from the csv file?

Code for reading csv file:

```
    func readfileFloat(fileName: String) -> [Float] {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "csv")

    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let scanner = NSScanner(string: content)
        var result = [Float]()

        while !scanner.atEnd {
            var x: Float = 0
            scanner.scanFloat(&x)
            result.append(x)
        }

        return result
    }  catch _ as NSError {
        let mf: [Float] = [0.0,0.0]
        return mf
    }
}
```

The performance with this code is really poor. It takes almost 4-5 seconds to read the files I need to load.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would consider using `NSKeyedArchiver` to persist the data so you only have to scan the file in once.
2. To load the data on launch, do so in the app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function. I would recommend doing the csv loading within a `dispatch_async` thread so your UI doesn't get bogged down while it's loading.
3. Another easy way to persist data is `NSUserDefaults`.

**Update**

Here is how you would implement something like this in the `AppDelegate`. Mind you, it's in Swift, since I don't know Objective-C just yet. easy enough to translate over though.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "csv")

    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let scanner = NSScanner(string: content)
        var result = [Float]()


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            while !scanner.atEnd {
                var x: Float = 0
                scanner.scanFloat(&x)
                result.append(x)
            }

            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(result)
            let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
            let documentsDirectory = (paths[0] as NSString)
            let filename = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(NSUUID().UUIDString)
            data.writeToFile("values", atomically: true)

        })

    }  catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    return true
}
```

Then whenever you want to access the file:

```
let filename = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(NSUUID().UUIDString)

if let values = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(filename) as? [String] {
    csvValues = values
}
```

This should be a good starting point for you. Keep in mind you'll only need to do this once since the data is persisted, so it doesn't need to execute every time you load the app. You might want to wrap this in logic that checks if the object is already archived. Hope this helped!

Comment: My data is static. Could you please give an example on how to use NSKeyedArchiver; then call it in app delegate's function and then pass it into function which is written in ViewController.m ?

Comment: Here is another thing. I have .txt file from which the data can also be read.

Comment: If this solved your answer, would you mind accepting the answer?